# Enable remote JMX on Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, jmx

I'm trying to enable remote JMX on a Jetty 6.1.26 instance running on Windows.
I have tried several approaches, but the result is always the same:

When I try to connect from jconsole to `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi` I got "connection refused".

I have found several guides on the internet, but no one seems to help.
Please note that I'm running Jetty standalone, from the "Jetty-Service.exe" wrapper.

It would be great if someone could suggest a way to enable remote JMX on jetty.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have network/firewall issues? Can you `ping` the remote machine and connect to 1099 using `telnet`/`nc`? If port is the problem, maybe try [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/features-nb.html)?

Comment: I'm running the Jetty instance locally. The local firewall is disabled, just in case. I can't telnet to 127.0.0.1 1099

Comment: Ok, looks like I managed to connect. I have to start Jetty from the commandline with the following args:                                java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -jar start.jar etc/jetty-jmx.xml etc/jetty.xml

Comment: your right... i got it to work that way, but only if I didnt edit the etc/jetty-jmx.xml config file.  i cant get it to work by editing that file alone.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

This is the way I have found to start Jetty with JMX enabled:

```
java
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 
-jar start.jar etc/jetty-jmx.xml etc/jetty.xml
```

Comment: Note: this solution works perfectly for jetty-runner too. Used with 9.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Which Jetty is this? I had to do the same yesterday. First, I had to uncomment etc/jetty-jmx.xml in the start.ini file (installation root.) Then I had to add the same jmx system properties that you mentioned in your comment above. Unless you edit start.ini, you will not see the Jetty-specific MBeans, but you will be able to connect via jConsole.

Comment: The version of jetty is 6.1.26 (as specified in the original question)